# How send file using PHP and Curl

Tags: php, curl

How can I execute such request using PHP and Curl?

```
curl -v  -X POST  --data-binary @"myJpegFile.jpg" http://bol.cinovatech.com /newcrunch/1441749032/MmRhMmYwYzk4OWY2Y2IyNzNlNTU1MmMwOTUyNTE5YzY4YjJiOTIxNg==   > outPutFile.jpg
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for send file :-

```
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'file' =>
          '@'            . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
          . ';filename=' . $_FILES['file']['name']
          . ';type='     . $_FILES['file']['type']
    ));
```